# Find the tan A if the triangle is inside the square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

[image: figure given]

ABCD is a square. The problem asks for me to find $\tan(\angle QAP)$ if I am given the fact that $CP = CQ = \frac{AB}{4}$.

This is what I have so far:

I drew a line from $Q$ to $P$ to make triangle $QAP$ a right triangle. Therefore, if triangle $QAP$ is a right triangle, then $\tan(\angle QAP) = \frac{PQ}{AP}$.

For $PQ$: I used the Pythagorean Theorem on sides CQ and CP to find PQ. $(\frac{AB}{4})^2 + (\frac{AB}{4})^2 = (PQ)^2$. Simplifying gives me $PQ = \frac{AB}{2\sqrt{2}}$.

For $AP$, I used the Pythagorean Theorem on AB and BP. Since BP = BC - CP, $BP = \frac{3AB}{4}$. Using the Pythagorean Theorem with AB, I got: $AP^2 = (\frac{3AB}{4})^2 + (AB)^2$, which gives us $AP = \frac{5AB}{4}$.

Since $\tan(\angle QAP) = \frac{PQ}{AP}$, plugging in what I have for PQ and AP and doing some simplification gives me $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{5}$. However, that answer is correct. Did I make a minor mistake anywhere? I can't seem to find my error.

Comment: You can't make QAP a right triangle.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is that $\Delta QAP$ is not a right triangle.

This problem is fairly easy if you assign coordinates. Let $A = (0,0)$, $B = (4,0)$, $C = (4,4)$, and $D = (0,4)$. Then $P = (4,3)$ and $Q = (3,4)$.

From here, it is easy to calculate the slope $m_1$ of $AQ$ and the slope $m_2$ of $AP$.

Then, $\tan \angle QAP = \tan(\angle QAB - \angle PAB) = \dfrac{\tan \angle QAB - \tan \angle PAB}{1+\tan \angle QAB \tan \angle PAB} = \dfrac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}$.

Comment: For $m_1 = \frac{4}{3}$ and $m_2 = \frac{3}{4}$. Plugging this in, I get $-\frac{7}{24}$, but I'm not sure why it is negative. Is it supposed to be?

Comment: I believe for the numerator it should be $m_1 - m_2$, not $m_2 - m_1$.

Comment: ^Thanks for catching that. I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

If $CP = CQ = \frac{AB}{4}$, then let $CP = CQ = 1$.

From that, we can deduce $PB = 3, AB = 4$.

$\angle PAB = tan^{-1} (\frac {3}{4})$

$\tan \angle QAP = \tan (\frac {\pi}{2} – 2 \cdot \angle PAB)$